# Any way to safely delete a feature branch after rebasing it onto another?

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-rebase

How can I *safely* delete my local copy of a feature branch when it's rebased onto origin/master instead of merged. I know I can `git branch -D`, but I'd like to avoid doing that blindly and let git tell me which branches are safe to remove.

E.g.: I have feature branch `my-feature`, I push it to `origin/my-feature`, make a PR, and `origin/my-feature` gets rebased onto `origin/master`, and then deleted. The local `my-feature` still remains though.* Is there any way to detect that the changes there have been effectively included in `origin/master`?

`git diff origin/master...my-feature` doesn't work, because the common ancestor with `origin/master` hasn't changed. Checking that `git diff origin/master..my-feature` is empty works, but only immediately after rebasing. If any other changes get rebased on top of mine, this will show those changes.

Is there a way to delete local branches whose remote versions have been deleted? (But *not* local branches that never had remote versions). Or, if I avoid deleting `origin/my-feature`, is there something I could then do locally to delete both `origin/my-feature` and `my-feature` safely?

* If I'm disciplined enough, I try to always remember to delete my local branch immediately after the remote branch gets deleted, but sometimes I forget.

Comment: use git cherry in this situation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git cherry` was perfect, never knew about that. I made an alias to clean up all branches that have been merged into `upstream/master`:

```
branch-cleanup = "!f(){ for b in $(git for-each-ref refs/heads --format=\"%(refname:short)\"); do if [[ ! $(git cherry -v upstream/master $b | grep \"^+\") ]]; then git branch -D $b; fi; done };f"
```

A little bit more readably:

```
for b in $(git for-each-ref refs/heads --format="%(refname:short)"); do  # Go through each branch
  # git cherry prefixes each commit with "+" if it's not included and "-" if it is, so check if there are no "+" lines:
  if [[ ! $(git cherry upstream/master $b | grep "^+") ]]; then
    git branch -D $b
  fi
done
```

Comment: This will delete the local `master`, won't it?

Comment: Yeah, but I don't keep a local master branch around.

Comment: I made a small improvement as such so it doesn't delete the local `master`, `develop` and `dev` branches: `for b in $(git branch --format="%(refname:short)" | grep -vE "(master|develop|dev)"); do  # Go through each branch
  # git cherry prefixes each commit with "+" if it's not included and "-" if it is, so check if there are no "+" lines:
  if [[ ! $(git cherry origin/master $b | grep "^+") ]]; then
    git branch -d $b
  fi
done`

Answer (score 2):

Let me insert a bit of background information first.  I believe you are talking about what happens when someone uses the "rebase and merge" clicky button on GitHub.  This copies the commit(s) to a new set of commits added to the tip of the target branch:

```
...--o--o--*--o   <-- master
            \
             A--B--C   <-- pullrequested
```

becomes:

```
...--o--o--*--o--A'--B'--C'   <-- master
            \
             A--B--C   <-- pullrequested
```

This means that `git branch --merged` is not helpful: it will test whether commit `C` is an ancestor of commit `C'`, and `C` is not an ancestor of `C'`.

(Annoyingly, GitHub's "rebase and merge" clicky button seems to re-copy the commits to new hash IDs even in cases where it should not be necessary.  This might be to make the author and committer separate, for pull requests where one has no direct access to the original repository.  Anyway the result is that the tip of your pull-request branch, such as `C`, is not an ancestor of the tip of the target branch, such as `master`.)

> Checking that `git diff origin/master..my-feature` is empty works, but only immediately after rebasing.

Not only that, but the diff is generally only empty if there were no extra commits, i.e., if the overall graph looks like:

```
...--o--o--*--A'--B'--C'   <-- master
            \
             A--B--C   <-- pullrequested
```

As [Andrew C comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45963244/any-way-to-safely-delete-a-feature-branch-after-rebasing-it-onto-another#comment78887321_45963244), you can use `git cherry` to see if all the commits (here, `A-B-C`) were copied.  It might be nice if someone were to bundle this into a script.